# React: callback url not found in ie

Tags: reactjs, react-router, service-worker

I use react-router and service worker in my web application.

When i enter the url likes below directly in the address bar or callback from the backend server.

```
https://www.sample.com/function
```

It works well in chrome beacause the service worker is runing in the background.
But the ie doesn't support service worker, so i got a not found page.

I found only the newest browers can support service worker.
Is there other way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I also tried to do this, but not work.  <Route component={Top} />
<Redirect from="*" to="/" />

Comment: handle all routes in your backend code and return the same SPA?

Comment: I found the answer. I can use hash router. https://www.sample.com/#function